# Spring Data JPA, hibernate sort order by a subclass property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

- spring-data-jpa: 1.5.2.RELEASE
- hibernate: 4.3.5.Final

Is it possible to order by the attribute of a joined subclass in spring data jpa, this is the query that I'm trying to get working;

```
@Repository
public interface InventoryItemRepository extends JpaRepository<InventoryItem<Item>, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT inventoryItem FROM InventoryItem inventoryItem JOIN TREAT (inventoryItem.item AS Sword) item WHERE inventoryItem.player = :player")
    List<InventoryItem<Item>> getSwordInventory(@Param("player") Player player, Pageable pageable);

}
```

### Some example usage:

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10, new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, "item.name"))); // works as it matches on Item class
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10, new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, "amount"))); // works as it matches on InventoryItem class
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10, new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, "item.attack"))); // doesn't work, this is what I want to do
```

### This is what hibernate tries to execute:

```
Hibernate:
select
    inventoryi0_.id as id1_0_,
    inventoryi0_.amount as amount2_0_,
    inventoryi0_.item_id as item_id3_0_,
    inventoryi0_.player_id as player_i4_0_ 
from
    InventoryItem inventoryi0_ 
inner join
    Item item1_ 
        on inventoryi0_.item_id=item1_.id 
inner join
    Sword item1_1_ 
        on item1_.id=item1_1_.id cross 
join
    Item item2_ 
where
    inventoryi0_.item_id=item2_.id 
    and inventoryi0_.player_id=? 
order by
    item2_1_.attack asc limit ?
```

### The exception thrown

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "item2_1_"
```

### The entities

(I've stripped down most of it for presentation):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Long id;

    String name;
}

@Entity
public class Sword extends Item {
    Integer attack;
}

@Entity
public class Shield extends Item {
    Integer defence;
}

@Entity
public class InventoryItem<T extends Item> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    Player player;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Item.class)
    T item;

    Integer amount;
}
```

Comment: The above uses JPA 2.1, I also used the following query for JPA 2.0 which gave the same error;

@Query("SELECT inventoryItem FROM InventoryItem inventoryItem JOIN inventoryItem.item item WHERE inventoryItem.player = :player AND type(item) = :type")

Comment: The JPA 2.1 spec (4.4.9) states: "The use of the TREAT operator is supported for downcasting within path expressions in the FROM and
WHERE clauses. Use of the TREAT operator allows access to subclass-specific state." So may not be available in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I also get the same result when using type(item) = : type for JPA 2.0

Looking closer, it makes a cross join back on the Item table then uses that to do the ordering.